# Invalid or unrecognized option in Linux when first argument begins with dash `-`

Tags: bash, printf

How can I print a double dash (`--`) with `printf` in bash?
I tried the following but none worked:

```
$ printf "--moish"
$ printf -- "moish"
$ printf "\-\-moish"
$ printf "$-$-moish"
```

Here are the corresponding outcomes (an error followed by the other three)

```
bash: printf: --: invalid option
printf: usage: printf [-v var] format [arguments]
```

Then:

```
moish
\-\-moish
himBHshimBHsmoish
```

Comment: There's a related post over at Unix&Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/490933.

Comment: `printf -- "--moish\n"` (POSIX requires `--` to indicate end-of-options when the first non-option argument begins with `'-'`)

Comment: Another related post at Super User https://superuser.com/questions/1371834/escaping-hyphens-with-printf-in-bash

Comment: `printf "%s\n" "--moish"`

Comment: Edited question title to make it a bit broader since this does not only involve `printf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `bash` evaluates quotation marks first, the final line evaluated is

```
printf --moish
```

which makes the error more evident. This is a common mistake in bash, where your first non-flag argument begins with a dash (`-`), and it does not matter it is double. This also happens with `grep` often as far as I have noticed. This makes the tool think you sent it a flag rather than the argument.

Most if not all tools (since this is a POSIX thing) allow for a `--` flag for this case exactly - explicitly telling the tool that everything thing after is a regular argument, and not a flag:

```
printf -- --moish
```

Note the quotes are not even mandatory. They would be though if you wanted

```
printf -- "--moish\n"
```

to prevent premature evaluation of "\n".

Answer (score 1):

use -- just after printf to specify following arguments are not command switches

so for your case use:

```
$ printf -- "--monish\n"
--monish
```